# Is there a USB micro SD card reader in a sturdy metal keychain thumb drive form factor?

Tags: usb, microsd, flash-drive

I'm looking for a USB thumb drive to keep on my keychain, but with removable (therefore replaceable and upgradable) microSD storage rather than flash memory that is built into the device. There are of course hundreds of options for something like this, but I'm looking for a specific set of features.

Basically, I'm looking for something like the Kingston Datatraveler or the similar Samsung thumb drive (photos below), but with removable microSD storage.

- Metal unibody construction
- USB type-A connector built into the body (not a slide-out connector or one with a detachable cap)
- Large hole at one end for a keyring, also built into the body of the device and not a tether cord or plastic piece. Ideally the hole would be like the Kingston model below, so the whole device is flat and lays flat with keys on the keyring)

Kingston Datatraveler:

[image]

Samsung thumb drive:

[image]

I imagine the micro SD card would be installed similarly to how this device works: the card is inserted into the USB connector itself. I actually have one of these exact readers and it works well but is way too flimsy for daily duty on my keychain:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After some poking around, the closest I came to meeting your question's requirements was this: **[Black Aluminum MicroSD USB Card Reader works with all sizes TF card capacities](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=microsd%20flash%20drive%20keychain%20aluminum&oq=microsd%20flash%20drive%20keychain%20aluminum&gs_l=serp.3...13013.14717.0.14845.9.9.0.0.0.0.144.974.0j8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.7.865...33i160k1j33i21k1.D8IFLy0vHfc)**.

---

Meets most of your requirements:

- Fixed USB A connector
- Works as a micro-sd adapter/flashdrive
- Intended to be used for keyring-carry

Doesn't quite meet these requirements:

- Metal unibody construction, the aluminum casing covers everything except the ends. (good enough though?)
- Does not include a large key-chain hole. You can get around this issue by adding a larger split circular key-chain on to the included one.

---

You can buy this MicroSd Card reader/flashdrive [from Newegg for $6.](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0UW0YM8623&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Card%20Reader%2FAdapter-_-9SIA0UW0YM8623&gclid=Cj0KEQiAifvEBRCVx5up6Ojgr5oBEiQALHw1TinINIaRF4KMILU0ixUBKO8es0NXu5aNVovLIF5Q0HEaAlqC8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds)

You can buy 25mm/~1" split circular key-rings also [from Newegg for about $1.](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAAUJ41K8289&cm_re=split_key_ring-_-9SIAAUJ41K8289-_-Product)

Answer (score 1):

Naztech makes a device they call the "Xtra Drive Mini" that is something like what I am after:

[image]

It's made of aluminum, takes a microSD card, and attaches to a keyring. It has shortcomings though:

- Non-retractable (read: easily broken) proprietary Lighting connector
  with a removable (therefore loseable) cap.
- No keyring hole like the DataTraveler or Samsung above.